# Color used for group is not transferred to particles

Tags: particles, color

I am doing my first steps with Blender and ran into a problem I couldn't solve so far. I have a group consisting of 6 objects and I assigned the same material to all of the group members. Now I used this group as particle in a plane and I would love them to have the same color as the original objects. On the left in the picture are my objects and on the right they are as particles in the plane. [image]
I am using the cycles render if this makes a difference. This is how I made the color for the material:
[image]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shader uses the *Geometry > Position* output to set the gradient. This output is just the World-Space (absolute) location of the point being shaded, so as your particles move up and down they will move "through" the gradient, or in your particular case, just sit above it.

Instead, use the *Object* output on the texture coordinate node. This will factor in the transformation of the object being shaded, so the gradient remains the same no matter where the object appears, or how it is scaled or rotated.

**Note:** The texture coordinate nodes' *Object* output has a field to specify a reference object. Leave this blank so the node will instead use the object currently being shaded.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Though now the color ramp is not smooth anymore but goes instantly from one color to the other.

EDIT: Changed the 'Texture Coordinate' to _Generated_ and it works